# Case when to update multiple columns at once

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, case

I have never used Case before and am not sure how to do this but we have had some issues doing a wholesale update because of addresses changing that are now coming in the data that did not used to.  I am trying to use it as an if then statement but I am sure that I am doing wrong.  I need to update addresses when a field is either empty or null.

```
UPDATE    defendants_ALL_Fixed
SET              tiffAdd = tiffAdds.Add1, tiffZip = tiffAdds.Zip, tiffCity = tiffAdds.City, tiffState = tiffAdds.State
FROM         defendants_ALL_Fixed INNER JOIN
                      tiffAdds ON defendants_ALL_Fixed.tiff = tiffAdds.Tiff
WHERE     (defendants_ALL_Fixed.tiff = tiffAdds.Tiff)
```

I have tried wrapping that into a case statement such as:

```
SELECT
  a.tiffAdd
, CASE WHEN a.tiffAdd = '' THEN

UPDATE    defendants_ALL_Fixed
SET              tiffAdd = tiffAdds.Add1, tiffZip = tiffAdds.Zip, tiffCity = tiffAdds.City, tiffState = tiffAdds.State
FROM         defendants_ALL_Fixed INNER JOIN
                      tiffAdds ON defendants_ALL_Fixed.tiff = tiffAdds.Tiff
WHERE     (defendants_ALL_Fixed.tiff = tiffAdds.Tiff)

END
FROM defendants_ALL_Fixed a
```

Which did not work and I understand why it does not work but have no idea where to go from here and any help would be great.  We only use this once a month to update data (about 1.5 million records) and the resources it uses is not at all relevant at this point.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming i am understanding your question (i.e. only update `defendants_ALL_Fixed` fields with `tiffAdds` when the `defendants_ALL_Fixed` fields are blank), you could do this as follows (sticking with case):

```
UPDATE  defendants_ALL_Fixed
SET     tiffAdd = CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(tiffAdd, ''))) = '' THEN tiffAdds.Add1
                       ELSE tiffAdd
                  END ,
        tiffZip = CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(tiffZip, ''))) = '' THEN tiffAdds.Zip
                       ELSE tiffZip
                  END ,
        tiffCity = CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(tiffCity, ''))) = '' THEN tiffAdds.City
                        ELSE tiffCity
                   END ,
        tiffState = CASE WHEN LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(tiffState, ''))) = '' THEN tiffAdds.State
                         ELSE tiffState
                    END
FROM    defendants_ALL_Fixed
        INNER JOIN tiffAdds ON defendants_ALL_Fixed.tiff = tiffAdds.Tiff
```

A simpler (or rather, easier to read) option is to do simple update statements based on a `WHERE` clause (one update statement per column):

```
UPDATE  defendants_ALL_Fixed
SET     tiffAdd = tiffAdds.Add1
FROM    defendants_ALL_Fixed
        INNER JOIN tiffAdds ON defendants_ALL_Fixed.tiff = tiffAdds.Tiff
WHERE   ( LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(tiffAdd, ''))) = '' )
```

**Edit 1:** based on your comment, That would suggest you can just update all columns where tiffAdd = ''? i.e.

```
UPDATE  defendants_ALL_Fixed
SET     tiffAdd = tiffAdds.Add1 ,
        tiffZip = tiffAdds.Zip ,
        tiffCity = tiffAdds.City ,
        tiffState = tiffAdds.State
FROM    defendants_ALL_Fixed
        INNER JOIN tiffAdds ON defendants_ALL_Fixed.tiff = tiffAdds.Tiff
WHERE   LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(tiffAdd, ''))) = ''
```

Comment: It only needs to update when tiffAdd is null or empty and that is why I was trying to wrap it as opposed writing a case statement for each but I just changed each line to be tiffAdd.  Thank you!

Comment: @korrowan See Edit 1 on my answer, if you only want to update where tiffAdd = '' you dont even need to use CASE, just add a WHERE clause onto the update statement.

Comment: what are the implications of leaving out WHERE     (defendants_ALL_Fixed.tiff = tiffAdds.Tiff) ?  Is that not needed because of the INNER JOIN?

Comment: You dont need `defendants_ALL_Fixed.tiff = tiffAdds.Tiff` in the `where` clause as your already specifying this in the `ON` clause of the join, you only used the `WHERE` clause in joins on the old non ANSI style joins

Comment: Gotcha!  I originally tried to do it with the where clause and assumed the defendants_ALL_Fixed.tiff = tiffAdds.Tiff was screwing it up but I had no idea I didn't need it.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use merge instead? Use merge on every each field, checking if the value is not null or empty. I think it wpould be the best (used it on my own solution).